# Is it possible to ignore files when copying directories in a yeoman generator?

Tags: glob, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm trying to write a yeoman generator and at one point I need to copy the files/folders of a github repo to the current working directory, eg:

```
this.remote('owner', 'repo', function (err, remote) {
    remote.directory('.', '.');
});
```

However I want to ignore some of the files in this repo, is it possible to do so? I found the [function responsible for this](http://yeoman.io/generator/actions_actions.js.html#line144) but it doesn't seem to be a clear way to do it, there's a `process` function that you can pass but I'm not sure if you can "cancel" a file being copied if it matches a certain pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rely on the [`this.fs` object](https://github.com/SBoudrias/mem-fs-editor) rather than the old depreciated files methods.

Helper methods on `this.fs` support glob patterns, so ignoring some files become trivial.

You can learn more about Yeoman file system here: http://yeoman.io/authoring/file-system.html

Comment: Yes I ended up using the `this.fs.copy` method and a glob pattern to match the files in the `remote.cachePath` location to ignore the ones I don't need. Not sure if it's the best approach but it seems to work for what I need for now.

Comment: Yup, that's the best approach. Further improvement could be to just rely on npm to fetch the repository instead of doing it at run time using `this.remote`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that last bit? I'm curious about how that'd look like.

Comment: Just `npm i --save https://github.com/some/package`. Then you just copy from the `node_modules` folder.

Comment: I see, well in my case the repo isn't always the same it can by customised by prompting the user so I guess using `remote` is good enough.

Answer (score 2):

From the mem-fs-editor [docs](https://github.com/SBoudrias/mem-fs-editor#copyfrom-to-options-context-templateoptions-):

> For a globified from, you can optionally pass in an
>   options.globOptions object to change its pattern matching behavior.

See the options [here](https://github.com/mrmlnc/fast-glob#options-1):

Example:

```
this.fs.copy("<from path>/**", "<to path>",
  {
    globOptions: {
      ignore: [
        globs to ignore...
      ]
    }
  }
);
```